# Can I access a hash stored in html elements data attribute with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got several html elements that I'm appending hashes to like so:

```
<p class='message' data-dependencies={'#first':{'equal':'Yes'}}>
  Relevant Content
</p>
```

so that

```
$(".message").first().data("dependencies")
```

returns

```
{'#first':{'equal':'Yes'}}
```

But as a buddy just pointed out to me, this value is a string. So naturally the filter described below has a hard time with it.

The goal of the filter is to be able to grab elements that have a specified key, in this case "#first".

```
$el.children().find("*").filter(function(){
    var dependency_hash = $(this).data("dependencies");
    if(dependency_hash != undefined && "#first" in dependency_hash){
      return true
    }
});
```

Is there a way to access the hash as passed via the data object or is there another way I can structure the data so as to accomplish the same means of being able to select elements based on the key?

Comment: If you just care whether they have that key then `return dependency_hash.indexOf("'#first'")!=-1;` should do it. If you need to actually get the value or use it as an object then `dependency_hash = JSON.parse(dependency_hash);` will create an object from the string. _Except_ that valid JSON should use double-quotes, not singles - can you reverse the double- and single-quotes? `data-dependencies='{"#first":{"equal":"Yes"}}'`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by storing that data on the DOM element?  There is probably a better way to do this.  Storing state information in the DOM like that is generally a bad practice.

Comment: It's not state related, it has to do with display properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you store it as valid JSON, you can parse it, and get is content.

```
<p class='message' data-dependencies='{"#first":{"equal":"Yes"}}'>
  Relevant Content
</p>
```

---

```
var json = $(".message").first().attr("data-dependencies");

// HTML5 browsers
// var json = document.querySelector(".message").dataset.dependencies;

var parsed = $.parseJSON(data);

alert(parsed["#first"].equal); // "Yes"
```

---

Or if you use jQuery's `.data()`, it will parse it automatically.

```
var parsed = $(".message").first().data("dependencies");

alert(parsed["#first"].equal); // "Yes"
```

Comment: Accepted for completeness and helping me realize using double quotes for the data string was a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON.parse. There are polyfills if you need support in older browsers.

```
$el.children().find("*").filter(function(){
    var dependency_hash = $(this).data("dependencies");
    var parsed_hash = JSON.parse(dependency_hash);
    if(parsed_hash != undefined && "#first" in parsed_hash ){
      return true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to serialize your data as JSON http://json.org/ and then get it back in JS.
You can use jquery's parser http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/